# In a class with multiple teachers, how can I transform student scores based on their teacher's average compared to the population average?

Tags: data-transformation, normalization

It has been ages since I've taken any statistics courses, and I have found myself in the following situation:

I am in charge of a university course with about 400 students and 10 assessors.

There is a presentation-style activity coming up, during which any given student will be graded by one of the assessors. Each assessor will have about 30, 40 students.

We have a rubric for grading, but historically there is a lot of variation in each assessor's average, standard deviation, range, etc. Teaching beliefs and expectations of students are very hard to change!

I would like to "normalize" student scores, so that any given student's assessor's mean would be compared to the population mean, and then that student's score would be scaled up or down accordingly.

Ideally, perfect scores (say, 20/20) would not change. I imagine as scores get closer to full points, the shift up or down would be less significant. Lower scores will be scaled a lot more.

To me, this sounds logarithmic, but I don't have the slightest idea how to go about it.

I am making a spreadsheet to handle this, so I was hoping for some mathematical formula to use. I am quite adept with Excel, and I have a strong mathematical background (at least I thought I did!), so complexity of the formula is not really a problem.

I don't remember a whole lot of terminology, however, so please be patient with me! And please let me know if more details are needed.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you assume each assessors' scores are normally distributed, then you can compute [standardized scores](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_score) for each student as

\begin{equation}
z=\frac{x-\mu}{\sigma}
\end{equation}

where *x* is the student's score, $\mu$ is the mean score of the student's assessor, and $\sigma$ is the standard deviation of the student's assessor's scores. Here is an example in R.

```
# Simulate 40 generous and 40 grumpy assessor scores
set.seed(23)
x1 <- rnorm(n=40, mean=13, sd=3)
x2 <- rnorm(n=40, mean=8, sd=2)

# Standardize student scores based on their assessor
z1 <- (x1 - mean(x1))/sd(x1)
z2 <- (x2 - mean(x2))/sd(x2)

# Plot distributions of unstandardized and standardized scores
layout(matrix(1:4, 2, 2))
hist(x1, main="Generous assessor- unstandardized", xlim=c(4, 22))
abline(v=mean(x1), col="red")
hist(z1, main="Generous assessor- standardized", xlim=c(-3, 3))
abline(v=mean(z1), col="red")
hist(x2, main="Grumpy assessor- unstandardized", xlim=c(4, 22))
abline(v=mean(x2), col="red")
hist(z2, main="Grumpy assessor- standardized", xlim=c(-3, 3))
abline(v=mean(z2), col="red")
```

[image: histograms]

You can see that the unstandardized scores are biased by the assessor, but the distributions of standardized scores are roughly normally distributed around 0.

Comment: pl. explain calculation of student's assessor mean and population mean with example.

Comment: I added an example, is that what you mean?

Comment: Hey Slow loris,

I think this does it! The only other step would be to transform the range of [-3,3] to [0,20], which is trivial.

Thanks so much!

I feel like an idiot because I recall this formula being like the first thing you learn about in statistics courses :P

Comment: What do you mean transform the range [-3,3] to [0,20] and how is that trivial?

Comment: The range of the above graphs is -3 to 3, which is the number of standard deviations from the mean if I recall. Is that correct? Grades must actually fall between 0 and 20, so my first instinct was to use the population mean as the 0 above, then use the population standard deviation to calculate transformed scores. I'm trying that now to see if it  gives me the values I am looking for. Maybe it's not so trivial as I expected, actually....?

Comment: For example, if a standardized student score is -1.75, I would take the population average, and from that subtract 1.75 times the population standard deviation to arrive at the transformed score.

Comment: I don't understand why you would go back to the scale 0-20. The point of standardizing is that you can now compare all students, even if they had different assessors. You can now decide on percentile cutoffs for grades (e.g., top 5% of scores are an A+).

Comment: We wouldn't use percentile cutoffs for grades for a myriad of reasons, many of which probably wouldn't be appropriate to discuss here as it doesn't really pertain to the question (I'd assume).

Comment: In short, we have some ethical qualms with assigning an arbitrary (5%, 10%, etc.) cutoff for As, Bs, and so on. A student's measure of achievement shouldn't be affected by the number of students that are performing to the course's standards. Besides, a 20-point scale works better with other scores that we have collected from our various graded components. Thanks for the help, though! It looks like this data is exactly what I was looking for :)

Comment: I think you are contradicting yourself a bit. You say "student's measure of achievement shouldn't be affected by the number of students that are performing to the course's standards", in other words, the measure of achievement should be absolute, not relative. But the whole point of standardizing your scores is to relativize them- once you have relativized them, you cannot un-relativize just by stretching out the distribution.

Comment: You are correct, I recognize my position is a bit... contradictory. I am in the position of making sure students have a fair shot at getting a good score, regardless of how 'grumpy' their assessors are. I am trying to adjust for the teacher's biases, and the problem is that Teacher A consistently scores between 18 and 20, while Teacher B scores between 9 and 12. Absolute scores would not be appropriate in this case, as it is simply a matter of luck of the draw whether a student gets a good or bad score.

Comment: I am working on the *assumption* that students who score higher compared to their peers within their teacher groups would have scored higher in a different teacher group. I am not prepared to take the next step, though, and say only 10% of students actually performed to a reasonable expectation (which is my definition of an A, btw--achieving the course objectives, not being the 'best of the best' or whatever)

Comment: Oh okay. So your issue is with what percentile cutoffs to use, not whether percentiles are the way to break things down. I have no issue with that!